# How to export data and its label into a single excel sheet-when data generated through double-for-loop

Tags: r

How to export data and its label, heading, information-about data for layman understanding- into a single excel sheet when the data is generated through double-for-loop at different stages within single iteration.
 Code:

```
 k=3
 t=2
   o=seq(from=1, to=t, by=1)
    for(i in 1:t){
        v=((o[i])+1)
        print ("treatments")
        print (v)
        h=seq(from=0, to=o[i], by=1)
        q1=NULL
        q2=NULL
        x1=NULL
           for(j in 1:o[i]){
              q1=c((v-(4*h[j]+1)))
              q2=c(((4*h[j])+2))
              T=c(q1,q2)
              y=c(0)
              IB=c(y,cumsum(T)%%v)
              print("The Initial Block(s) is/are=")
              print(IB)
                   p=seq(from=0, to=v-1, by=1)
                   l=NULL
                     for(i in 1:k){
                     for(j in 1:v){
                     l=c(l,rep((IB[i]+p[j]+v)%% v))
                     }
                    }
              x= matrix(c(l),nrow=k,ncol=v,byrow = TRUE)
              x1=cbind(x1,x)
                }
         print ("Design Matrix is")
         print (x1)
       }
```

At first iteration, the output is:

```
        [1] "treatments"
        [1] 3
        [1] "The Initial Block(s) is/are="
        [1] 0 2 1
        [1] "Design Matrix is"
        [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    0    1    2
 [2,]    2    0    1
 [3,]    1    2    0
```

At 2nd iteration, the output is

```
  [1] "treatments"
  [1] 5
  [1] "The Initial Block(s) is/are="
  [1] 0 4 1
  [1] "The Initial Block(s) is/are="
  [1] 0 0 1
  [1] "Design Matrix is"
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    1    2    3    4    0    1    2    3     4
 [2,]    4    0    1    2    3    0    1    2    3     4
 [3,]    1    2    3    4    0    1    2    3    4     0
```

and so on ...

please consider

1. The output may be in the sequence as mentioned on single excel sheet of a file.
2. Matrix may be cell by cell-- I have tried but it pasted in single cell.
3. Please ask if something ambiguous.
4. Codes are very lengthy so one may take his/her own example please.

Comment: There are two packages that specialize in this.  Did you look at them?  Did you read the documentation?  Did you try the examples?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel. I tried xlsx package and also online help but cannot understand this completely.

Comment: What motivation do I have to write my own example code when chances are that my example will deviate from your needs in some small way which will lead you to complain about how my solution doesn't work, and then you'll demand that I address this "issue"?

Comment: @jouran can i paste whole code here, otherwise question stay ambiguous?. I already warned for putting my whole code here.

Comment: @ZaheerAbbas, it is best not to post a whole project here no, but if you could make a small toy example of your loops, that produces say a little 4x4 matrix. People can then help show where you are going wrong. Think of a minature version of your project that gets to the root of the problem.

Comment: We don't want your whole code. It's your job to create a _small_, **reproducible** example.

Comment: @joran the question is edited. please consider it

Comment: @user1317221_G is it make sense now?

Comment: I think it makes more sense to put create this as a PDF from R as text and tables, then provide the matrices separate if people need the data then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, this is a terrible, terrible way to display information.

```
library(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook("~/Desktop/so/terrible_idea.xlsx",create = TRUE)
sht <- "Horrible Way To Display Data"
createSheet(wb,name = sht)

k=3
 t=2
   o=seq(from=1, to=t, by=1)
    for(i in 1:t){
        v=((o[i])+1)
        print ("treatments")
        appendWorksheet(wb,data.frame("treatments"),sheet = sht,header = FALSE)
        row_counter <- row_counter + 1
        print (v)
        appendWorksheet(wb,as.data.frame(v),sheet = sht,header = FALSE)
        h=seq(from=0, to=o[i], by=1)
        q1=NULL
        q2=NULL
        x1=NULL
           for(j in 1:o[i]){
              q1=c((v-(4*h[j]+1)))
              q2=c(((4*h[j])+2))
              T=c(q1,q2)
              y=c(0)
              IB=c(y,cumsum(T)%%v)
              print("The Initial Block(s) is/are=")
              appendWorksheet(wb,data.frame("The Initial Block(s) is/are="),sheet = sht,header = FALSE)
              print(IB)
              appendWorksheet(wb,as.data.frame(IB),sheet = sht,header = FALSE)
              row_counter <- row_counter + nrow(as.data.frame(IB))
                   p=seq(from=0, to=v-1, by=1)
                   l=NULL
                     for(i in 1:k){
                     for(j in 1:v){
                     l=c(l,rep((IB[i]+p[j]+v)%% v))
                     }
                    }
              x= matrix(c(l),nrow=k,ncol=v,byrow = TRUE)
              x1=cbind(x1,x)
                }
         print ("Design Matrix is")
         appendWorksheet(wb,data.frame("Design Matrix is"),sheet = sht,header = FALSE)
         print (x1)
         appendWorksheet(wb,as.data.frame(x1),sheet = sht,header = FALSE)
       }

saveWorkbook(wb)
```

Comment: thanks dear. I trying to install all needed packages. I will let you know if it works.

Comment: I have installed package `XLConnect` but there is still these errors   `Loading required package: XLConnectJars    
   Loading required package: rJava     
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded`

Comment: @ZaheerAbbas If you bothered to Google that error message (as I just did) you'd learn that it simply means that you don't have Java installed on your computer (or the registry that says where it is installed is corrupted).

Comment: thanks dear a lot, through this, values of Initial block comes in a single column, the output looks more better if it converts into a row. I have tried my best with these codes for conversion but failed. thanks again.